# Disable selection of future dates in multiple months datepicker jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

So i have a multiple month datepicker, when i move to a new month/year I wish to have  all the other month dates disabled, still visible but not selectable. could anyone suggest an idea, thnks

Comment: Use the `beforeShowDay` callback to determine which days are selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Correct i was playing with beforeShowDay option ( http://jsfiddle.net/201bb1pr/ ),i.e.

```
$('input').datepicker({
numberOfMonths: 3,
beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [ dates_array_of_new_month.indexOf(string) != -1 ]
}
```

});
,but as far I understand i need to get all the dates of the new month , How do I get them